# prevent re-inserting data

Tags: php, codeigniter, double-submit-prevention

Hello everyone dose anyone know any tutorials that explain how to using sessions to prevent re-inserting data or some other form of method in a form. And if u have any suggestions in how to do this do not hesitate to post your ideas tnx in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=prevent+double+submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a design pattern, called the [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) designed solely to avoid the re-submission of data. Basically, the idea is, when the user has submitted their content, the page is redirected, meaning there is no chance of a re-submission.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for tnx for your help Chris.